# Invalid Column name 'xxx'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I did 2 codes, following the oriented-object method. One of them is a DatabaseConnection code where you can find kind of querys, connection and disconnections from server.
My DatabaseConnection class is doing fine, but I have a problem with the App class, because by doing the oriented-object method, so I can't use this code in App class:

```
PreparedStatment ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1,x);
ps.setInt(2,x);
```

...etc
because the PrepareStatement is in DatabaseConnection class.
So I replaced it with a String.format as I can show you:

```
String varidProduct=new String();
String varNameProduct=new String();
String varBrandProduct=new String();
int varPriceProduct;
String varDate=new String();
int varquantStorage;

     System.out.print("Please write ID: ");
     varidProduct = input.readLine().trim();
     System.out.print("Please write product name: ");
     varNameProduct=input.readLine().trim();
     System.out.print("Please write the brand: ");
     varBrandProduct=input.readLine().trim();
     System.out.print("Ingrese el price: ");
     varPriceProduct=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine().trim());
     System.out.print("Please insert the date (day/month/year): ");
     varDate=input.readLine().trim();
     System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad en Bodega: ");
     varquantStorage=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine().trim());

     String sqlCommandText = String.format("insert into Product values (%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%d)",varidProduc,varNameProduct,varBrandProduct,varPriceProduct,varDate,varquantStorage);                                            





      if(connection.executeSQLcommand(sqlCommandText)>0)
                //I am calling here a method in DatabaseConnection.class
          System.out.println("The information has been inserted.");
      else
         System.out.println("The information has not been inserted.");
      }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage());} 

     }
```

If I insert just numbers as varidProduc, varNameProduct, varBrandProduc, varPriceProduct and varDate, the system respond me with an update, but if I write strings (because in my DB SQL server 2008, this columns are all varchar except for date) the system respond me with an exception of "Invalid Column name". I don't know what I am doing wrong here, seriously.
Sorry if I am missing something in my spelling, I am from Chile and I am trying my best! haha

I did just read some of other answers about Invalid Column Name but noone of them were related to my problem.

Thanks for your time! please let me know if you need more details!

Answer (score 0):

Quote your string values in the SQL statement if you insist on using / must use `String.format` to construct your SQL:

```
String.format("insert into Product values ('%s','%s','%s',%d,'%s',%d)",
    varidProduc,varNameProduct,varBrandProduct,
    varPriceProduct,varDate,varquantStorage);
```

else the values will be interpreted as an identifier, in this case, a column name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I already tried that, with '%s' and \'%s\', but the insert just work (or return me an int) if I use values(111,111,111,11/11/11,11), I mean if I use numbers, the problem is when trying to use strings.
I am using a BufferedReader too.

Answer (score 0):

the First step would be to write the insert statement to be more readable:

```
INSERT INTO Product (Column names here) VALUES (Column values here)
```

the real problem is that your string values %s should be escaped like this:

```
'%s'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried that too, by using '%s' and \'%s\', but noone works.

Comment: could you provide the database query with the column names?
maybe one of the column name is not allowed

Comment: Yes, I used that too:
String sqlCommandText = String.format("insert into Product (idProduct,nameProduct,brandProduct,priceProduct,creationDate,quanStorage) values ('%s','%s','%s',%d,'%s',%d)",varidProduct,varNameProduct,varBrandProduct,varPriceProduct,varDate,varquantStorage);

4 of 6 are varchar, but if I use a numbers in varchar columns the statement works, but if I use strings in varchar columns the code returns me an Exception :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the forward slashes in your date string '/' , I think you have to escape the forward slash for sql and u have to use '\' as the escape character.

```
So finally your code should be something like this : 

After reading the date....
vardate.replace('/','\\/');

String sqlCommandText = String.format("insert into Product values ('%s','%s','%s',%d,'%s',%d)",varidProduc,varNameProduct,varBrandProduct,varPriceProduct,varDate,varquantStorage)

Try using this. Let me know if this works..
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I am sorry but it didn't work.. because the issue is not in there. Everytime I want to add a varchar with %s, the System returns me an Exception that the "string" failed to insert. This codes just let me add numbers but strings. The return Exception is "(idProduc,nameProduct,brandProduct,priceProduct,creationDate,quantInStorage) values (aaa,Car,Lexu,50000,12/08/2012,100)"
Then.. --> Invalid Column Name 'aaa' is invalid, idProduct is a varchar(20) as primary key in server.